# Should i create window instance with empty contructor

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a situation where in solution there are two project. A controls library and main application.

Now i want to create DialogFactory that will handle initialization of dialogs.

Let's say the structure is like this

> Application.Presentation
>
> - MainWindow.xaml
> - **ChartDialog.xaml  (edited name)**
>
> Application.Presentation.Controls
>
> - DateTimeDialog.xaml
> - ColorPickerDialog.xaml

Flow is like this:
**MainWindow** opens dialog **Window1** that opens dialog **DateTimeDialog**

I want to create interface that will be referenced by both projects to handle dialog creation.

DialogFactory should look like this:

```
public interface IDialogFactory<T> where T:Window
{
    T FetchDialog();

    void Release(T instance);
}
```

For this to work all Window/Dialog constructors should be empty. 
This means that any additional value should be passed
 via Init method.

So the example would work like this

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
openDialog_Click(...)
{
    Window1 dialog = dialogFactory.FetchDialog<Window1>();
    dialog.Init(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    dialog.Show();
}
```

**Window1.xaml.cs**

```
openDialog_Click(...)
{
    Control1 dialog = dialogFactory.FetchDialog<DateTimeDialog>();
    dialog.Init(arg1);
    dialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

I want to know is this a good practice or if you know of a better way?

Comment: any additional value could be passed via window `DataContext` property

Comment: That is right. So only reason to pass an argument to constructor of a window would be to set its DataContext inside the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this.

```
public interface IWindowFactory
{
    IWindow Get(IViewModel viewModel);
}
```

Then you control how your windows or dialogs are created based on your view models. You can easily mock it for unit testing and you only need to know about `IWindow` interface.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I like this. Maybe more generic? T1 GetWindow<T1, T2>(T2 context) where T1 : IWindow where T2 : IViewModel;

Comment: Thanks for the up vote.
I would think twice before exposing the View type. If you are developing MVVM, usually you do not want to know view details. By exposing the view type, unit test will probably become more complicated.

Comment: That is true. I could make it so that i implement type selector in IOC container and resolve window by naming convention. It would be light version of Bradley's solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply implement a `DialogService` that handles the creation of the dialogs?

```
public interface IDialogService
{
    void ShowDialog(string title, string message);
}

public class DialogService : IDialogService
{
    public void ShowDialog(string title, string message)
    {
        //implement your actual dialog however you want there...
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(message, title);
    }
}
```

Then you could pass in as many arguments you want to the `ShowDialog` method and implement it however you want.

A dialog service shouldn't derive from `Window`. It is simply a service with the sole purpose of displaying dialogs.

The best practice would be to implement a view model class with an `IDialogService`. You can then easy replace the implementation with a dummy service that doesn't display a dialog in your unit tests.

Comment: Can you please show me how you would show more complex dialog in your sample? I do not have just title and message properties

Comment: Can't you just add some parameters to the ShowDialog method? ShowDialog(string, string, object, int, ...)?

Comment: You can take a look at the source code for a library that I maintain that does something similar. https://bitbucket.org/BradleyUffner/wpflib/src/ae1e68dc83a2/WpfLib/Services/WindowManager/?at=master .  It is entirely view model based though, so everything is passed through that.

Comment: @mm8 No, let's say that Window1 is ChartDialog that needs to have DataTable binded to its view. Inside this ChartDialog you can open a printing dialog to print the chart.

Comment: I don't think I understand the issue, You can implement the IDialogService interface however you want and you can have multiple implementations of it. Just create a class that implements the interface and put all your dialog logic in there. It the dialog itself is dependant on the specific window somehow, it probably doesn't make sense to use a separate dialog class in the first place.

Comment: Sure, that is ok. I was thrown off by the interface definition. If i implemented it like `void ShowDialog<TWindow, TViewModel>(string title, TViewModel) where TWindow : new() where TViewModel : IViewModel` i would get what i want.